# title does not change when in Category joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla

I have created one website using joomla 2.5
I have created one item: shop
I went out the home page, and click on the link categories: shop
the title of this page, the same as the title of the home page: Home
if now I want, page headers categories: shop "shop" What do I do

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correct. But you may want to have a look at the menu item parameters. On the right side there is a slider named "Page Display Options". This allows to specify a title for the browser tab and the page heading.
There is also a parameter in the Joomla Global Configuration in the "Site" tab in the "SEO Settings" section named "Include Site Name in Page Titles". This allows to specify if the site name should be added to the page title or not.

Hope that helped, otherwise please specify your question.

Comment: thank you
his own game
you can go to the home page: http://localhost/mb, the title: home
when clicked can type shop (http://localhost/mb/12-shop), the title it still is: home
now how, to alone title into http://localhost/mb/12-shop, it coincides with the category name

Comment: He, I can't access your localhost :)
Maybe you can post some screenshots.

Comment: you can access: http://rao.noi24.com
Title to the home page and category pages, they are completely identical

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to understand the language so I just clicked a bit around on the site. The title is indeed not changing. But then the generated URLs also look a bit strange. Are you using a special extension there? Either for the items or for SEF?

If you're using the core content then the page title is usually taken from the active menu item, not the category title itself. Joomla tries to find a matching menu item and if none is found it takes the currently active one.
So maybe try to create a menu item for the category in question and see if that helps.